# Issue with date increment

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am able to increment and decrement a date in my blackberry app.

The issue comes when I change some data in popup screen and click on next the date remains the same without incrementing however the long value is same as the incremented value.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String dateFormat = compareDate; //mar 28,2012-compare date value
String m = dateFormat.substring(0, 3); 
String dd = dateFormat.substring(4, 6); 
String y = dateFormat.substring(7, 11);
dateFormat = dd + " " + m + " " + y; // 28 mar 2012

long dateLong = HttpDateParser.parse(dateFormat);
long ctimeMinus50Days = dateLong + 1L * ((long) DateTimeUtilities.ONEDAY); 
calendar.setTime ( new Date(ctimeMinus50Days) ); 
System.out.println("ctimeMinus50Days" + ctimeMinus50Days);

Date d = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sd1Exactform = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy"); 
sd1Exactform.format(d);

if (dateCurrent != null) {  //static value so making null before assigning new value
    dateCurrent = null; 
}
dateCurrent = sd1Exactform.format(d);
```

`ctimeMinus50Days` value is same when is works for increment, but when I see `dateCurrent` output it's the old date only even though long value shows incremented data.

Comment: Consider to use java.util.date to normalize data in unix timestamp format. You can avoid a lot of problems using maths on that format and using dd mm yyyy format just for user presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this class

```
public class DateUtilities {
    static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    public static long getPreviousDate(long currentDate){
        calendar.setTime(new Date(currentDate));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1);
        return calendar.getTime().getTime();
    }
    public static long getNextDate(long currentDate){
        calendar.setTime(new Date(currentDate));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
        return calendar.getTime().getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calendar class exposes add method which you should use to add/subtract date elements. Here's an example to add one day to a date represented by the string:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String dateCurrent = "Mar 1,2012";
    SimpleDateFormat sdExactform = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy");
    Date date = sdExactform.parse(dateCurrent);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(calendar.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: and to subtract a day you simply need to 'add' a negative eg. `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);`

Comment: @daniel calendar.add is not part of blackberry calendar api